# I have every problem like this. does anyone know how to fix it? thank you

Tags: java

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ditmI.png)

```
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=QLSV;user=sa;password=12345";

try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();) {
    String SQL = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM USERS";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

    // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("USERNAME") + " " + rs.getString("PASSWORD"));
    }
} // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of questions with that exact error message. Please do a search first. And please write a better subject!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the project is maven please update the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.1.jre11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: không phải dự an maven ạ :((